# PBR material broke in cycles renderer but works in eevee

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, texturing, uv, eevee-render-engine

First of all , I really like blender community addons and this is a house I made with only using addons.

#### Addons

Building tools addon 
Lily Surface Scrapper

I make the building and added pbr textures with scraper addon , and used smart uv unwrap , then assigned the materials made by scraper.It works well in eevee renderer but in cycles they are going nuts. Either in workspace or rendered image.

**What I tried :** tried mark seams and unwrap maually , tried triangulate modifier with every possible options none of them worked.

**Eevee Result** 
[image]

**Cycles Render** 
[image]

Guess this is an issue every beginner faces, but I couldnt find any answer.

### Note

Tried lily scrapper wit default shapes and a little extruded custom shapes they worked well in both renderer. 
  I can't add .blend file because it won't mean anything without the textures.

Comment: Try changing mapping to "generated".

Comment: From where i will do that ? I'm a begginner .

Comment: See https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/interface/index.html#window-system

Comment: That is ... really not helpful.The link you gave is like equal to giving the home page of billion page docs.If you know the problem , try explaining it. As i said i am a newbie.

Comment: I tried adding texture coordinate node and connect generated option  either directly image texture node's vector  or with interpreting mapping node . Didn't worked.